# How to hide JqGrid search operators dropdown?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need to hide the search operators dropdown in the search dialog of the jqGrid control. Could you please tell me how this is done?

Please see the image below

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: You want to hide it and use always equal operator?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to use a wild card searching on specific columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see wiki: [Single field searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching)

e.g:

```js
$(s4list).jqGrid('searchGrid', {
  multipleSearch: true,
  afterShowSearch: function () {
    var dialogId = $('#fbox_' + this.id);
    dialogId.find('.operators').hide();
    console.log(this)
  }
})
```

also

afterRedraw function:This function if defined is lunched every time the filter is redrawed - the filter is redrawed every time when we add or delet rules or fields Tio this function we pass the search parameters as parameter

Comment: `afterShowSearch` will work only in case of simple searching dialog. If you use `multipleSearch: true` or `multipleGroup: true` then there are exists additional buttons in searching dialog. If you would click for example "Add rule" button then the fields will be recreated and the previously hidden fields will be shown, Because of the reason I suggest to use `afterRedraw` callback instead which works with every searching options.

Comment: wiki [Advanced Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching) .Please read wiki : "We have the same options as those from Single Searching "

Comment: You use `multipleSearch: true` option so if the user clicks on "Add rule" button then the hidden field will be visible. If you want to use `afterShowSearch` instead of `afterRedraw` then one have to use `multipleSearch: false` and `multipleGroup: false` option. The usage of `afterRedraw` have no restrictions and it can be used in every scenario.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use in your tests?

Comment: @Oleg - jqGrid  4.6.0

Comment: Just try the first demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/o6g9rnug/1/ which uses *your code* in jqGrid 4.6, open the searching dialog - you will see that `.operators` dropdown is hidden. Then click on "Add rule" button on top, right of the searching dialog. You will see two rules **with shown `.operators` dropdown**. Now you can try the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/o6g9rnug/2/ where `afterRedraw` will be used instead of `afterShowSearch`. The `.operators` dropdown is hidden and it stay hidden after clicking on any buttons of the searching dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Searching dialog allows to specify `afterRedraw` callback which can be used to modify elements of the dialog. What you need is something like the following implementation

```
afterRedraw: function () {
    $(this).find(".operators").hide();
}
```

If you use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) then you can add jqGrid option (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods))

```
searching: {
    afterRedraw: function () {
        $(this).find(".operators").hide();
    }
}
```

to specify the callback. If you use jqGrid then you should specify `afterRedraw` in the list of parameter of `navGrid` (inside of the 5-th parameter):

```
$("#grid").jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {/*navGrid options*/},
    {/*edit options*/}, {/*add option*/},{/*del option*/},
    {
        afterRedraw: function () {
            $(this).find(".operators").hide();
        }
    }
);
```